# Reference request: extension of $*$-homomorphism to multiplier algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ a $^*$-homomorphism. Does $f$ always extend to a $^*$-homomorphism $\tilde{f}:M(A)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, where $M(A)$ is the multiplier algebra of $A$?

I suspect the answer is no, but I'm not sure how to show this. In case the answer is yes, a proof or reference would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes. This depends on two facts:

- $A$ is an ideal in $M(A)$.
- if $J\subset B$ is an ideal, any non-degenerate representation $J\to B(H)$ can be extended to a representation $B\to B(H)$. This is for instance Lemma I.9.14 in Davidson's C$^*$-Algebras By Example. Here we have $J=A$, $B=M(A)$, $H=\mathbb C$.

The argument works for any $*$-homomorphism $A\to B(H)$.

Comment: Can this somehow be used to show that any $*$-homomorphism of $C^*$-algebras $A\rightarrow B$ extends to a $*$-homomorphism $M(A)\rightarrow M(B)$? (I'm slightly worried about the non-degeneracy requirement in Davidson.)

Comment: As far as I can tell, you usually require the $*$-homomorphism to be onto for that. In that case, it looks like the above argument would indeed work.

Comment: If the representation $\pi:A→B(H)$ is degenerate,can we also get the unique extension $\tilde{\pi}:M(A)→B(H)$ by defining $\tilde{\pi}(\tilde a)=lim\pi(a)e_n$,where $\{e_n\}$ is a.u for A.

Comment: You will never get uniqueness of an extension of a degenerate representation; that's precisely the problem. As for the definition, I see no reason for your limit to converge.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2940320/is-the-extension-of-homomorphism-unique?r=SearchResults.You answered the question before.In Blackdar's book,there also states the non-degeneracy of the representation.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The fact that they agree on $A$ makes it unique.

Comment: Does it mean that we can remove the condition "the representation is nondegenerate?".

Comment: No. I have edited the other answer.